# Sed/Awk script to append/insert?

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, vi

I have a configuration file that looks like the example below. There are a series of definitions grouped by hostname. I just added the "cpu-service" definition to one host "mothership". Now I need to do this to 100+ more in the same file. What I have already done is scraped from config file all pre-existing host names (100+). So now I have a file with the list of servers that now need to have the cpu-service define comment. They already have ping-service so I just want to add the cpu-service to each one. Obviously manually doing this by hand would be tedious.

Is there a sed/awk script I could use to do this type of work. Basically I need to maybe write a skel file with the define part and leave host_name blank. Then feed the host.txt file into that. I could maybe hack this with some VI trickery as well. Not sure?

Thanks in advance!

```
 
define{
        use                             cpu-service
        host_name                       mothership
        contact_groups                  systems manager
}
define{
        use                             ping-service
        host_name                       mothership
        contact_groups                  systems manager
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed can insert newlines, just backslash escape them - e.g. the following will go through each line in your 'hosts' file, and replace it with a full definition for the cpu-service. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want.

```
sed -e 's/^(.*)$/define{\
    use                             cpu-service\
    host_name                       \1\
    contact_groups                  systems manager\
}/g' hosts.txt > new_directives
```

if you're happy with new_directives then you can just

```
cat new_directives >> config_file
```

NOTE you may get issues with blank/trailing newlines.

Comment: Where would I reference the host.txt file I have? Is -i .bak - myconfig.cfg.bak?

Comment: Also maybe I was not clear. The define cpu service is not there for anything but "mothership" The other 100+ servers only have ping-service defined. So this wouldn't work?

Comment: @ZackLee the updated answer may be closer to what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Although I got the slight feeling to do your work, try the script below:

```
 awk '
 BEGIN {
         RS = ORS = "}\n"
         FS = "\n"
 }
 NF > 0 {
         print
         if (sub(/ping-service/, "cpu-service")) print
 }
 ' file
```

One tradeoff: Somehow I get a trailing "}" but it is not worth worrying about, unless you got to make that every day - just remove it with an editor.

As always with *awk*: If your vendor ships an historic version of *awk* you may want to use *nawk*.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps mister:

1: Host name file (hostnames.txt)

mothership
motherload
motherofpeal
mothersbaugh

2: script (hostup.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=$1

TEMPLATE=" 
define{
        use                             cpu-service
        host_name                       ${HOSTNAME}
        contact_groups                  systems manager
}
define{
        use                             ping-service
        host_name                       ${HOSTNAME}
        contact_groups                  systems manager
}"

echo "${TEMPLATE}"
```

3: command line

chmod +x hostup.sh
 
while read name; do hostup.sh $name; done  < hostnames.txt
while read name; do hostup.sh $name; done  < hostnames.txt >> hosts.conf

Comment: Thanks mmrtnt. works almost to the point I need it. However, I already have motherload, motherofpeal, mothersbaugh with the ping-service defined. So really I need to insert cpu-service ontop of those already existing definitions. This is really close.